# NAVD88 not in Vertical Reference drop down list of Drone2Map

Tags: coordinate-system, vertical, egm96, drone2map

I use the Propeller company's Aeropoint GPS tiles to collect ground control for drone flights.

When trying to import my ground control points, the survey report provides the coordinate reference system in:
Vertical coordinate reference system: NAVD88 height
Vertical EPSG code: 5703
Geoid model: geoid12b

However, Drone2Map has a very limited selection of Vertical Reference options to choose from:

- EGM84
- EGM96
- EGM2008
- ELLIPSOID
- HEIGHT ABOVE ELLIPSOID

Can anyone help me choose the correct option?

Comment: depending on your coordinates https://doc.arcgis.com/en/drone2map/1.3/process-and-share/vertical-reference.htm but ArcGIS Online and ArcGIS Pro both use the EGM96 geoid height model.

Comment: Look into  https://vdatum.noaa.gov/about.html in your area -- There are signficant differences between NAVD88 and the GEOIDs.

Comment: Are you/can you set a horizontal (geographic or projected) coordinate reference system? It might be that NAVD88 is restricted to one of the NAD83 geographic CRS.